# TypeScript execution with inconsistent order

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am experiencing some issues on TypeScript 2.4.1, Node.js v8.1.3, and VS Code 1.14.0.

For some reason, my experimental code does not print in order. Especially rest and foreach section.

Here is my test page.

Am I missing something here?

**GggDataStructuresIntTests.ts**

```
var dotdotdotFun = function () {
    let [first, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    console.log("first", first); // outputs 1
    console.log("rest", rest); // outputs [ 2, 3, 4 ]
    rest.forEach((item) => {
        console.log("forEach", item);
    });
}
dotdotdotFun();
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "js/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015" ],        
        "watch": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser"
    ]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Node.js",            
            "program": "${file}",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/js/**/*.js"
            ]
        }        
    ]
}
```

There is some outputs;

Output 1:

[image]

Output 2:

[image]

Output 3:

[image]

Comment: That's perfectly valid javascript, so I doubt typescript has got anything to do with this. Popping your snippet into my browser console behaves as expected (first, rest, then foreaches)

Comment: @Rob hmm, so you think it might be TypeScript compiler is messing with order?

Comment: If it *is* typescript, that would be an extremely large bug in the compiler. I'm almost positive it's nothing to do with typescript. Perhaps node is doing something fishy (or perhaps another piece of code is invoking the method on a different thread)

Comment: I see, maybe I should include node 8.1.3 version in the question, because I am running under node debugger as well.

Comment: If you did not provide screenshots I would have said "I don't believe it". Even with screenshots I don't believe it's possible though.

Comment: How did you setup your project? That is, what does one have to do to reproduce your results?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I added tsconfig.json and launch.json in the question for vscode.

Comment: It's as if the `console.log` function is an asynchronous function. Depends on the browser and libraries used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [Yeshan Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8118437/yeshan-jay)'s comment, I did more research on console.log() over Node.js [v8.2.0 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html).

There is a statement like below;

**Console**

> Warning: The global console object's methods are **neither consistently
>   synchronous** like the browser APIs they resemble, **nor are they
>   consistently asynchronous** like all other Node.js streams. See the note
>   on [process I/O for](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o) more information.

So seems like it is not fault of TypeScript compiler at all. (I checked also compiled JS, and everything was fine). Since I was running compiled js via Node.js engine, issue was starting from that moment. That's why issue cannot be reproducible at browser level.

I did not check with prev Node engines, but on this new version (>= 8) seems like console.log() should not be assumed as synchronous at all.